# Left outer join to Top 1 row of the table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a following query. I would like left outer join with first row of billing table which has same key as detail table.

```
SELECT e.id,a.empid,CASE WHEN ISNULL(bill.key,0) <> 0 Then 'Yes'
      ELSE 'No' END as billing  
from
(SELECT customer, accountid from employee e, account a where e.Id = a.empId) w, 
detail d LEFT outer join billing bill
        on bill.key = d.key

WHERE d.detailid = w.accountID
```

Issue: billing table can have multiple keys but I would like to only join one key to detail table. I am trying to find if it contains bill key or not. Right now Left outer join does not work correctly because it returns more than one result so my query is not returning correct results.

Comment: Do you want any data from `billing` other than the `key`?

Comment: @Nick No, I do not. I only want to know if there is a bill or not. Case statement does that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use outer apply

```
   SELECT e.id,a.empid,CASE WHEN ISNULL(bill.key,0) <> 0 Then 'Yes'
          ELSE 'No' END as billing  
    FROM
    (SELECT customer, accountid from employee e, account a where e.Id = a.empId) w, 
    detail d OUTER APPLY (SELECT Top 1 key FROM billing bill2 where bill2.key = d.key) bill


    WHERE d.detailid = w.accountID
```